# Add null to the columns which are empty

Tags: perl, awk

I am trying to put null to the columns which are empty using `perl` or `awk`, to find the number of column , header's column count can be used. I tried to perform the solution using `perl` and some regex. However, the output looks very close to the desired output but if noticed carefully row number one is showing incorrect data.

Input data:

```
id      name           type          foo-id  zoo-id  loo-id-1  moo-id-2
-----  ---------------  -----------  ------  ------  ------  ------
0      zoo123        soozoo          8               31        32
51     zoo213        soozoo          48      51
52     asz123        soozoo          47      52
53     asw122        soozoo          1003    53
54     fff123        soozoo          68      54
55     sss123        soozoo          75      55
56     ssd123        soozoo          76      56
```

Expected Output:

```
0      zoo123        soozoo          8       null      31        32
51     zoo213        soozoo          48      51        null      null
52     asz123        soozoo          47      52        null      null
53     asw122        soozoo          1003    53        null      null
54     fff123        soozoo          68      54        null      null
55     sss123        soozoo          75      55        null      null
56     ssd123        soozoo          76      56        null      null
```

Very close to solution but row-1 is showing incorrect data:

```
echo "$x"|grep -E '^[0-9]+'  |perl -ne 'm/^([\d]+)(?:\s+([\w]+))?(?:\s+([-\w]+))?(?:\s+([\d]+))?(?:\s+([\d]+))?(?:\s+([\d]+))?(?:\s+([\d]+))?/;printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n", $1, $2//"null", $3//"null",$4//"null",$5//"null",$6//"null",$7//"null"' |column -t
0   zoo123  soozoo  8     31  32    null
51  zoo213  soozoo  48    51  null  null
52  asz123  soozoo  47    52  null  null
53  asw122  soozoo  1003  53  null  null
54  fff123  soozoo  68    54  null  null
55  sss123  soozoo  75    55  null  null
56  ssd123  soozoo  76    56  null  null
```

Comment: You will need to split the data by column numbers because there's no separator between columns and any null column not in the trailing columns will be misinterpreted.  That's pretty painful.  With GNU `cut`, you could use `cut --output-delimiter='|' -c 1-7,8-21,22-37,38-45,46-53,54-63,64-` to get pipe-delimited output fields.  Then spotting the empty fields and replacing the data with `null` is fairly easy.

Comment: Do your underlines on line 2 really not align with the headers in line 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have a fixed-width string to parse, you'll find that [`unpack()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack) is a better tool than regexes.

This should demonstrate how to do it. I'll leave it to you to convert it to a one-liner.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

while (<DATA>) {
  next if /^\D/; # Skip lines that don't start with a digit

  # I worked out the unpack() template by counting columns.
  my @data = map { /\S/ ? $_ : 'null' } unpack('A7A14A16A8A8A8A8');

  say join ' ', @data;
}

__DATA__
id      name           type          foo-id  zoo-id  loo-id-1  moo-id-2
-----  ---------------  -----------  ------  ------  ------  ------
0      zoo123        soozoo          8               31        32
51     zoo213        soozoo          48      51
52     asz123        soozoo          47      52
53     asw122        soozoo          1003    53
54     fff123        soozoo          68      54
55     sss123        soozoo          75      55
56     ssd123        soozoo          76      56
```

Output:

```
$ perl unpack | column -t
0   zoo123  soozoo  8     null  31    32
51  zoo213  soozoo  48    51    null  null
52  asz123  soozoo  47    52    null  null
53  asw122  soozoo  1003  53    null  null
54  fff123  soozoo  68    54    null  null
55  sss123  soozoo  75    55    null  null
56  ssd123  soozoo  76    56    null  null
```

Comment: can you please tell how you calculated `'A7A14A16A8A8A8A8'` or a simple resource to read ? official document is difficult to understand for me. Thanks.

Comment: @monk: The section on strings in [perlpacktut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut) would be a good place to start. But it's 'A' (meaning treat the data as a string) followed by a number that is the width of the column (which I got by just counting characters in your input data).

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk 'NR>2{                     # ignore first and second row
       NF=7                    # fix number of columns
       for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)    # loop with all columns
         if($i ~ /^ *$/){      # if empty or only spaces
           $i="null"
         }
       print $0}' FIELDWIDTHS='7 14 16 8 8 10 8' OFS='|' file | column -s '|' -t
```

As one line:

```
awk 'NR>2{NF=7; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~ /^ *$/){$i="null"} print $0}' FIELDWIDTHS='7 14 16 8 8 10 8' OFS='|'  file | column -s '|' -t
```

Output:

```
0        zoo123          soozoo            8         null  31          32
51       zoo213          soozoo            48        51    null        null
52       asz123          soozoo            47        52    null        null
53       asw122          soozoo            1003      53    null        null
54       fff123          soozoo            68        54    null        null
55       sss123          soozoo            75        55    null        null
56       ssd123          soozoo            76        56    null        null
```

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, **OFS**, RS, ORS, **NR**, **NF**, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: Isn't that specific to `gawk` / non-posix? Also, you could set `FIELDWIDTHS` dynamically from the first or second line (if it is reliable)